# Web Font Sass Mixin Issue

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to import a web font using a sass mixin with the following extensions, .eot, .woff, .ttf

Here are the fonts file location.

[image]

For some reason the font is not rendering? I'm unsure why.

Here is my SASS mixin:

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: $font-family;
        src: url('#{$file-path}.eot');
        src: url('#{$file-path}.woff');
        src: url('#{$file-path}.ttf');
    }
}
```

Usage: `@include font-face(Roboto-Regular, '../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular');`

This is a create-react-app. I'm using sass along with my component.

See here for folder structure as the compiled .css sits within the component folder.

[image]

Comment: you need to provide the file path from the `compiled css` reference. probably something like `\assets\fonts\roboto-regular`?

Comment: Hope you are using the file path in your variable.

Comment: @Prajwal he is using sass variable of `$file-path` in that case he doesn't need to rewrite the whole thing again. Its not making sense

Comment: I will provide more information.

Comment: @Filth in network tab, are you seeing `404` next to font URL?

Comment: @Prajwal Good suggestion to check, no 404 errors.

Comment: @Filth is the font file is loading? Also, is there any class which uses the mentioned font family?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@include font-face(Roboto-Regular, '../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular');`

as 'assets' is sibling of 'components' folder and generated 'compiled.css' is inside  'components' folder.

Comment: I tried this but failed to compile... Module not found: Can't resolve '../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.eot'. I noted in the error message that it's trying to find the fonts within the component folder? That doesn't make sense? in 'Documents/Development/VOO/voo_web/src/components/Hero'

Comment: Ok, i confused with "component" / "components" folder.

Try to pass font name as string 
i.e
@include font-face("Roboto-Regular", '../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular');